# I have flexbox layout onclick i want to replace some images with one bigger

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

[image: I have images like this build in flexbox]

Onclick I want to change first image from first element with another which is bigger and takes 3 spaces from flexbox. I tried to do it on my own ,and on click 2 images hide which is ok but I can't make changed image bigger to fit into flexbox.

```js
function changeImage() {
document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "someimagepath";
  var x = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
```

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.container1 div{
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.sub-wrap {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.sub-wrap div {
  height: 50%;
}
.w-25 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.w-small {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}
.w-double {
  flex: 0 0 66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="w-25"><img src="image" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"></img></div>

  <div class="sub-wrap">
    <div class="w-small"><img src="image"id="imgClickAndChange1"></div>
    <div class="w-double"><img src="image" ></div>
    <div class="w-small"><img src="image" ></div>
    <div class="w-small"><img src="image" ></div>
    <div class="w-small">  <img src="image"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-25"> <img src="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: add html code...

Comment: if i give you example code with flexbox.. will be okay ?...you will made your own way

Comment: can i put answer ? do you need ?

Comment: check my ans..  further anything need  leave a comment ..

Answer (score 0):

it's a example code....

**use `flex:2`  instead of  `flex: 0 0 50%;` to `.sub-wrap` class and `flex:1` to `.w-25` class.. for trick..**

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.img')).forEach(function (el) {
          
        el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  
          flexShrink();
          e.target.style.flexGrow = '2';
        });
      });

      function flexShrink() {
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.img')).forEach(function (el) {
          el.style.flexGrow = '1';
        });
      }
```

```css
 * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #main {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
        display: flex;
      }
      .item {
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
```

```html
<div id="main">
     
      <div class="item img" style="background-color: lightblue">img</div>
      <div class="item" style="background-color: khaki"></div>
      <div class="item img" style="background-color: pink">img</div>
   
    </div>
```